# Why SIM Toolkit icon is duplicated (now tripled) in launcher?

Tags: lg, sim-card, launcher, app-drawer

**UPDATE:** It stopped happening after the latest OS (and launcher) update - to Android 8

---

Why does my SIM Toolkit icon is <s>duplicated</s> tripled?

The second one appeared not so long ago, and it never happened before (I have the phone for more than a year and a half).

There wasn't an OS update when it happened, or something I can think might affect, and there's only place for one SIM in that device.

Note:

- It happens only in that launcher.
- Reboot or re-inserting the SIM does not change it.
- Clearing launcher app cache doesn't help.
- I don't want to clear the app data, because I'll probably lose the organization of the apps.
- It appears only once in the app list in the settings.

***Device details:*** LG G5, Android 7.0, stock ROM, no root
***Launcher:*** Home & app drawer (By LG)

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Possibly your carrier installed a newer version of toolkit with updated settings. Check the app details for both

Comment: @beeshyams There's only one app - but it's shown twice in the launcher, so it's probably a launcher problem. The install date of the app as seen in App Detective is somewhere around 2008-2009, the same as other Android system apps. How can I tell if it was updated without me knowing about it?

Comment: See if [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) see package installer or other questions on this site to detect when the app was updated. Not sure how to go about

Comment: Did you find the solution bro? @arieljannai

Comment: @Noorul nope, it was gone after the latest os update 